# Fill out the height of a variable number of child elements, when the parent element has a fixed height

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-10

I have a container element that has a fixed height. **I want the child elements of this container element to completely fill the height of the container element, evenly distributing the height among the child elements.** The challenge here is that the number of child elements can vary between 2 and 5 elements.

```css
.container-element {
  height: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.child-element {
  background: grey;
}

.child-element:nth-child(even) {
  background: darkGrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content2
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content2
  </div>
</div>
```

My initial thought was to add a class to the container element that has the number of child elements that reside inside (i.e. `class="container-element elements-3"`), and make the height percentage of the child elements vary based on this class.

However, I was wondering if it was possible to fill the height of a parent , regardless of how many child elements exist, without having to add a different class to all the parent containers.

*Sidenote: This has to work in IE10*

**[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urtnw14x/2/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic case for a flexbox. Flexbox is [partially supported by IE10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh673531(v=vs.85).aspx) using the `-ms- prefix`, so this should work in IE10 (I've no way to check it):

```css
.container-element {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 200px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.child-element {
  -ms-flex: auto 1;
  flex: 1;
  background: grey;
}

.child-element:nth-child(even) {
  background: darkGrey;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container-element">
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content2
  </div>
  <div class="child-element">
    Dummy content2
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ash06229/urtnw14x/4/

It will work on IE-10.

Add following property to following class

```
.container-element {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
        -ms-flex-pack: justify;
            justify-content: space-between;
}

.child-element {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        -ms-flex: 1;
            flex: 1;
}
```